# How to get access token from facebook using spring boot security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have to get the access token from facebook using spring security, I have the following code for HTTP configuration

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/webjars/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/"))
        .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
        .and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
        .and().addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

Also, I am able to get the principal after login to facebook. But I need to get the logged in user access token.

These are the dependencies that I use for spring boot security,

```
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security.oauth.boot', name: 'spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure', version: '2.1.3.RELEASE'
```

This is the filter that I am using,

```
private Filter ssoFilter() {
    OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter facebookFilter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter("/login/facebook");
    OAuth2RestTemplate facebookTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(facebook(), oauth2ClientContext);
    facebookFilter.setRestTemplate(facebookTemplate);
    UserInfoTokenServices tokenServices = new UserInfoTokenServices(facebookResource().getUserInfoUri(), facebook().getClientId());

    tokenServices.setRestTemplate(facebookTemplate);
    facebookFilter.setTokenServices(tokenServices);

    return facebookFilter;
}
```

Is there any way to get the access token using spring boot security

Comment: Why are you manually adding a filter instead of using `@EnableOAuth2Sso`?

Comment: Instead, I am using `@EnableOAuth2Client` so I have added a filter manually. If I use `@EnableOAuth2Sso` can I be able to get the access token?

Comment: In general, there are ways (you can look how `OAuth2RestTemplate` itself does it); if you can explain what you're wanting to do with it that using the template transparently can't accomplish, that would be helpful.

Comment: Only thing is I have to get the access token, So I manually configured the filter and user the `@EnableOAuth2Client` if this could be achieved using the `@EnableOAuth2Sso` I would go for it

Comment: I got the access token from `OAuth2RestTemplate` after login to Facebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the facebook integration is correct with spring security, you could inject:

```
@Autowired
OAuth2ClientContext oAuth2ClientContext;
```

and with this object obtain the token:

```
oAuth2ClientContext.getAccessToken().getValue();
```